# Copy Jenkins project and replace strings in it

Tags: jenkins

I want to write a groovy script that will copy all projects from a given view to new view with new name (see code below) and also will change config - replace strings from old value to new value. 
I can copy jobs to new view, but how to modify them?
Lets say I need to change every occurrence of 'MR222' to 'MR999' in job configuration.

```
/* Variables */
def oldViewName = 'orig Name'
def newViewName = 'new Name'
def search = 'MR222'
def replace = 'MR999'

/* If new view doesnt exist create new view */
if ( ! Hudson.instance.getView(newViewName) ) {
    def newView = new ListView(newViewName)
    Hudson.instance.addView(newView)
    /* For each job in old view, copy it, replace workspace and add to new view */
    Hudson.instance.getView(oldViewName).getItems().each { item ->
      AbstractProject project = Hudson.instance.copy(item, item.getName().replace(search, replace))
      if (project.getCustomWorkspace()) {
        project.setCustomWorkspace(project.getCustomWorkspace().replace(search, replace))
      }
        newView.add(project)
      }
}
else {
  println "View \"${newViewName}\" already exist"
}
```

Comment: what property do you want to change ? i think find replace is not a way to do this. you have to work with object rather than xml string.

Comment: @mfidan Every occurrence of this string, it can be in parameters, in build steps, everywhere. For example 'MR222' can be passed as parameter in build step or can be a default value in parameter. I need to change it to new value.